# Did the "I have a dream" speech make a big impact at the time it was spoken?

Tags: civil-rights

Most Americans know the famous "[I have a dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Have_a_Dream)" speech by Martin Luther King. Was this speech actually influential back in 1963 or did it become famous afterwards?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It had a huge impact. Some would even say more than it has now. Out of the ten people that spoke that day, his speech was the most memorable and the one that really sparked the passion of the people.

Congressman John Lewis, who was the 6th speaker that day, describes MLK's words as "Streaks of lightning flying in the air." That speech and his notable role in the march on Washington contributed greatly to him getting a Nobel Peace Prize in 1964.

Comment: Sources would improve this answer.  Please provide a citation for the Lewis quote.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace how would I add a citation in the answer?